# Find row based on multiple conditions (column values greater than)

Tags: python, pandas

My issue is that I need to identify the patient "ID" if anything critical (high conc. XT or increase in Crea) is observed in their blood sample. 
Ideally, the sick patients "ID" should be categorized into one of the three groups which could be called Bad_30,  Bad_40, and Bad_40. If the patients don't make it into one of the "Bad" groups, then they are non-criticals

```
See  answer
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be the way:

```
critical = df[(df['hour36_XT']>=2.0) | (df['hour42_XT']>=1.5) | (df['hour48_XT']>=0.5)]
not_critical = df[~df.index.isin(critical.index)]
```

Before using this, you will have to convert the data type of all values to float. You can do that by using dtype=np.float32 while defining the data frame

Comment: to get id of not critical, you could use not_critical['id']

Answer (score 0):

You can put multiple conditions within one df.loc bracket. I tried this on your dataset and it worked as expected:

```
newDf = df.loc[(df['hour36_XT'] >= 2.0) & (df['hour42_XT'] >= 1.0) & (df['hour48_XT'] >= 0.5)])
print(newDF['ID'])
```

Explanation: I'm creating a new dataframe using your conditions and then printing out the IDs of the resulting dataframe.

Words of advice: You should avoid iterating over Pandas dataframe rows, and once you learn to utilize Pandas you'll be surprised how rarely you need to do this. This should be the first lesson when starting to use Pandas, but it's so ingrained in us programmers that we tend to skip over the powerful abilities of the Pandas package and immediately turn to using row iterations. If you rely on row iteration when working with Pandas you'll likely find an annoying slowness when you start working with larger datasets and/or more complex operations. I recommend reading up on this, I'm a beginner myself and have found [this article](https://engineering.upside.com/a-beginners-guide-to-optimizing-pandas-code-for-speed-c09ef2c6a4d6) to be a good reference point.